# Unable to send periodic local notifications with WorkManager after app is killed

Tags: android, notifications, android-sqlite, android-workmanager

I'm facing an issue that is wasting my time.
I'm building an app with a local `SQLite` database. I want this app to send a notification with some data from the `SQLite` database to the user every 15 minutes for example. I have successfully achieved this ***AS LONG AS THE APP IS RUNNING OR NOT KILLED*** But, when the app gets killed the notifications no longer appear to the user. I'm testing the app on two real devices ***Samsung & Huawei***. 
Here is the code for the notifier class that extends `Worker` :-

```
public Result doWork() {
    try {

      SqliteAssetHelper dbHelper = new SqliteAssetHelper(MainActivity.mcontext);
        mdatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        Cursor mCursor = mdatabase.query(BDH.BDHEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{BDH.BDHEntry.COLUMN_HADITH_ID,BDH.BDHEntry.COLUMN_BOOK_NAME,
                        BDH.BDHEntry.COLUMN_DOOR_NAME, BDH.BDHEntry.COLUMN_NARRATORS, BDH.BDHEntry.COLUMN_CONTEXT},
                BDH.BDHEntry.COLUMN_BOOK_ID+"=?",new String[]{"1"},null,null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 1");

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) { //You need to check if cursor doesnot contain last row
                    hadithID = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("HadithID"));
                    book = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("BookName"));
                    door = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("DoorName"));
                    mCursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        }

        Intent intentActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.mcontext, HadithActivity.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intentActivity.putExtra("id", hadithID );
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.mcontext, 0, intentActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.mcontext);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.mcontext,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.book)
                .setContentTitle(book)
                .setContentText(door)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
        return Result.success();

    }
    catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        return Result.retry();
    }
}
```

In the Main Activity I'm using the previous notifier to appear every 15 Minutes:-

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mcontext = this;


    //creating constraints
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setTriggerContentMaxDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();


    PeriodicWorkRequest showHadithEveryHour = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(HadithNotifier.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(showHadithEveryHour);
    }
```

When I change the notifier class code to show a log message without any values the Result for worker in the logcat is `Success`

```
Log.d(TAG,"Work Manager is working");
```

[image]
If I change the notifier class code to show a log Message with a value from the Cursor or to show a hard coded notification it doesn't work and the Result for worker is `Retry`.
[image]

Comment: " it doesn't work and the Result for worker is Retry" -- then log the `Throwable` that you are catching. If you log it, you will see a stack trace with whatever caused you to go into that `catch` block and return `Result.retry()`.

Comment: I am working on it I will show it to you once it appears in the log

Comment: @CommonsWare here is the throwable message :- 
` Workerjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At minimum, remove all references to `MainActivity.mcontext` from this class. Even better would be to remove `mcontext` entirely from the app, as it is a memory leak.

[Your `Worker` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker#Worker(android.content.Context,%20androidx.work.WorkerParameters)) is passed a `Context`. Hold onto it in a field, and use that `Context` from your `doWork()` method.

Comment: You know it operates every 15 mins so Once I finish testing I will tell you the result . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. it finally worked. Thanks again :)